# Remove non number data from an excel array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble using the method `LINEST` with data containing gaps. Order and remove the gaps by hand is not an option.

I have found this:
 `=LINEST(ISNUMBER(X_4)*Y_4,IF(X_4<>0,ISNUMBER(Y_4)*X_4^{0,1,2},0),0)`
from http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/using-linest-on-data-with-gaps/
but it does not deal with `#N/A` or `""` (blank) only null cells

My data can contain numbers, text, `#N/A` and blank. I need some way to get only the numbers, so I can use `LINEST`.

I also found this possible solution, but I can't make it work, I think there is some error in the formula:
`=LINEST(IF(ISNUMBER(C1:C9),C1:C9,),IF(ISNUMBER(C1:C9),CHOOSE({1,2,3},1,A1:A9,B1:B9),),)`
from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736549/ignore-n-as-in-excel-linest-function-with-multiple-independent-variables-known

Data sample:

```
X   Y
1   16,0
2   18,0
""  #N/A //Here I mean a blank cell, but non null, like an empty string ""
4   41,0
5   48,0
6   61,0
    #DIV/0!
```

The formula must ignore any non numeric row, the result must be the same of

```
X   Y
1   16
2   18
4   41
5   48
6   61
```

`LINEST` result: `a = 9,279069767`  `b = 3,395348837 [ y(x) = ax+b ]`

Comment: The second formula actually works in the data there. You need to press and hold the buttons Ctrl and Shift then press Enter/Return. If you want all three values, select three horizontal cells, type in the formula in the first cell, then press and hold Ctrl+Shift, then press Enter.

Comment: I know I need to press Ctrl+Shift... I can use Linest with only number data. The problem is data with gab or non number in the middle. The second formula was for a plane fit, and was unable to change it to a line fit.

Comment: You could also try these two with `Ctrl+shift+Enter`: `=SLOPE(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B6),B1:B6),IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A6),A1:A6))`   `=INTERCEPT(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B6),B1:B6),IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A6),A1:A6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula<sup>1</sup>:

> =LINEST(INDEX(A1:B6,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(MMULT(0+(ISNUMBER(A1:B6)),{1;1})=2,ROW(A1:B6)-MIN(ROW(A1:B6))+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/(MMULT(0+(ISNUMBER(A1:B6)),{1;1})=2))))))),2),INDEX(A1:B6,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(MMULT(0+(ISNUMBER(A1:B6)),{1;1})=2,ROW(A1:B6)-MIN(ROW(A1:B6))+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/(MMULT(0+(ISNUMBER(A1:B6)),{1;1})=2))))))),1))

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you first hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and only then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets `{}` around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).</sub>

Comment: This selects only one column? I need to fit a line into X and Y data. This formula only get x or y (I think). Can you please updated it?

Comment: So the rows to be considered should be only those where the data in EACH of the two columns is numerical?

Comment: Also - can you clarify what your expected result for the small dataset that you posted is?

Comment: Edited, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Don't know where you get the second part from - 3,395348837 - though I've amended the formula to apply to data in A1:B6.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks! Men, your formula is huge! Can you explain it? :) About my sample: y(x) = ax+b. a = 9,27, b = 3,39. Just select a 1x2 (row x column) and apply the array formula.

Comment: You're welcome! It's only huge since Microsoft evidently haven't given this function the ability to take Booleans for its arguments, which would seem to me to be quite an obvious requirement for a statistical function such as this. Oh well. I'll add some explanations to the post when I get chance later.

Comment: @XORLX agree it's complicated since Linest only allows numeric data in ranges. But there are some other functions like `SLOPE`, `INTERCEPT`, `FORECAST`, and `RSQ` that do allow for non-numeric data (as suggested in comment to post).

Comment: @lori_m Ah! That's more like it! Much more succinct. Good stuff. Will have to brush up more on these statistical functions. Though it does seem a tad inconsistent that SLOPE and INTERCEPT except Booleans but LINEST doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the blog linked in the question.

I have amended the LinestGap UDF so it will ignore any row with an error, "", or empty cell in any column.  The revised spreadsheet can be downloaded from: http://interactiveds.com.au/software/Linest-poly.xls

Comment: Thank you for the update. Excel really needs an updated. The methods just need an obviously "Must Ignore non numeric data" option. And the default value should be true, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I have had second thoughts on this.  It is not a good idea to ignore errors in the input data by default.  I have amended the code to provide an "IgnoreErrors" option, set to False by default.  It will still ignore any row with a blank or text in the x or y data.